# Making an array Field in Django

Tags: python, django, arrays, list

I need to make a model that stores the historical data of a Field, for example a poll that has a Field of its answers so it can make things with that. 
I was looking to the ManytoMany field but its too general, it feels like im doing too much for something easy.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. It sounds like you're asking for something like what Django does when recording changes made to objects through the admin interface.

Comment: @PeterRowell is right, there is already default database for that.

Answer (score 3):

Django 1.8 has support for an `ArrayField` [type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) that is PostgreSQL specific.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class ChessBoard(models.Model):
    board = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
            size=8,
        ),
        size=8,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it seems counter intuitive, but you definitely want to use something general like a many to one (foreign key) from your answers table to your poll table. You want your app to easily grow to support future ideas, like associating metadata with those answer-poll pairings, and being able to efficiently do queries on that metadata, like what do people in Portland answer to this question.

If you really want a deadend, dead simple, DB schema, just create an array of pks . But don't be tempted to use a postgres-only ArrayField. If you want your Django models to work with backends other than postgres (MySQL, MariaDB, or sqlite) you'll need to store your array as a string serialization. The easiest format would be a json string, but anything will do, even csv.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store previous versions of your models you could use [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion), which can add version control facilities to Django models (allowing you to save revisions, rollback changes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

We're using django-auditlog to do exactly what Django does recording changes through admin. https://github.com/Atomidata/django-audit-log
Implemented simply by specifying any model that needs to be audited.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True)
    field2 = models.BooleanField(blank=False,null=False,default=True)

    audit_log = AuditLog()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers but that is for changes in the model itself im looking for something that tracks he changes of a field, like some information people input so then it can be validated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the question directly, but I queried for "django create default arrayfield" and got here.

So, here is an example of creating an `ArrayField` with a default:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

def default_thing():
    return ['THIS IS A DEFAULT']

class SomeModel(ParentModel):
    thing_to_export = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), 
                                 default=default_thing)
```